# BRE error in IBM BPM - contract association

Tags: ibm-bpm

I got an error, when adding contract association with following BRE error in IBM BPM

**I got this Error message:**

> Error: The "Invoke MDM Service for Add/Update/History" service failed
>   with the following information:
>   com.ibm.bpm.wle.api.CouldNotSetPropertyException: CWTBG0535E: Property
>   'stringvalue' could not be set on a variable of class
>   'FormFieldDataObject'.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hi Hanumanthu sai srinivas, you just initialize the variable 'stringvalue' in your service like

```
tw.local.stringvalue = new tw.object.String();
```

this is perment fix for your problem